# Python Sockets Non-blocking Server using Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm building a peer-to-peer library in Python using TCP sockets and multithreading to handle peer connections. I'd like to have a `main.py` that creates an instance of a `Node` class, starts a server listening for connections on a port and then calls some methods of the class.

> e.x. main.py

```
from p2p import Node

a = Node(port=6666)
a.connect("138.197.105.184", 6666)
```

Since running the server is a blocking call, I'd like to run it in a separate thread so that the program can continue to do things (like connecting to other nodes) while also listening for connections.

The node runs `self.startServer` which starts the server in a thread.
New connections from the server are also processed in their own thread.

> p2p.py

```
def startServer(self):
        start_new_thread(self.startThreadedServer, ())

def startThreadedServer(self):
        while 1: # blocking call
            logging.debug("Waiting for connection")
            conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            logging.debug(conn + " " + addr)
            logging.info('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
            start_new_thread(self.clientThread ,(conn,))

def clientThread(self, conn):
        while True:
            #Receiving from client
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if is_json(data):
                payload = json.loads(data)
                reply = self.respond(payload)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(reply)
        conn.close()
```

However, when the server is run this way, all socket connections fail.

When I run `self.startThreadedServer()` as the server, it accepts connections but its a blocking call. No good.

How can I start the server and have the server continue to listen and accept connections in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misinformed as to how threads work. I thought that the program should terminate after running with threads running in the background. Instead, the program should NOT terminate at all.

Both nodes should actively listen for connections in a while loop. To achieve the desired functionality, the whole program should then be daemonized using something like `python-daemon` package.